# .htaccess read from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a simple .htaccess file for vanity URLs, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^example-category/?$   category.php?id=1  [NC]
```

The idea being that all category URLs instead of looking messy redirect to plain English versions.

My categories are stored in a MySQL database. So I'm wondering if it's possible (and advisable) to have the .htaccess file read directly from the database. This way if I add or delete a category the vanity URLs will update accordingly without manual intervention.

Is this a good idea? And if so how can you get a .htaccess file to read from MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you rewrite `^(.*)$` to `category.php?name=$1` and then lookup the relevant category from within that script?

Comment: Can you please talk me through what that line does? I'm brand new to the htaccess file. Thanks!

Comment: It would take whatever path is used, and then call `category.php` with the original path provided as the value to the `name` parameter (this latter part isn't strictly necessary, as PHP can always obtain the original path information using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`).

Comment: I would never automate anything about the .htaccess file. It is too important of a file and too dangerous in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the category `name` instead rather than using the `ID`. Here is a quick example.

htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEMAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEMAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^([^/]+)/?$   /category.php?name=$1  [NC]
```

This will take a URL like

`http://example.com/books/` and route it to your php file.

Then in your php file you can get it with something like this to use the `name`.

```
<?php

$cat = $_GET["name"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name='".$cat."'";

?>
```

That's not a complete PHP example. Just showing you how you can us the name instead of the ID. Note: I didn't take in consideration for security via mysql etc.